# I am unable to deploy my website to Netlify

Tags: github, web-deployment, netlify

I have been creating this website for a few weeks now (I am fairly new to web-dev) and have just recently made a repo (on Github) for it.

**Link:**

https://github.com/Lathryx/TopShelf-Recipes

I want to deploy with Netlify however I am unable to. Netlify continuously gives a 404 error on the site(s) that I create. I think it has something to do with the publish directory but I'm not sure. I want it to open to `landing.html`.

The few times I have tried to deploy now I have tried:

- No build command/publish directory.
- No build command and the publish directory set to `TopShelf Recipes`
  (have also tried `/TopShelf Recipes`).
- No build command and the publish directory set to `TopShelf Recipes/landing.html`.
- No build command and the publish directory set to `/TopShelf Recipes/landing`.

**Image of Error:** 
[image: Image of the error.]

I really don't know what to do. Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The landing page of your site *must* be titled `index.html` (as I’ve found), this fixed it for me. Mine (originally) was titled `landing.html`.

I will keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The [`netlify/my-first-netlify-deploys`](https://github.com/netlify/my-first-netlify-deploys) demo project shows files with a [`netlify.toml`](https://github.com/netlify/my-first-netlify-deploys/blob/master/netlify.toml) to adtually generates the files.

Result: https://playwith.netlify.app/

But if there are no generation involved, then said files should be directly at the root folder of the repository, not in a subfolder.

Comment: Thanks. As you can see on my repo (https://github.com/Lathryx/TopShelf-Recipes) I put all of the files in the root and it has yet to work! :(

Comment: Did you follow https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/10/27/a-step-by-step-guide-deploying-a-static-site-or-single-page-app/ (it might have changed since 2016 though)

Comment: It was actually just because the landing page *has* to be `index.html`. Mine was `landing.html` (as you do). Thanks for the help, though! ^-^